# True browser support of get/set/hasAttribute() etc

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

I recently came across a similar problem when researching the `readyState` property of the `document` object, where the `readystatechange` event was supported everywhere but the `readyState` property itself wasn't supported properly until ~IE9.

What I found out was that `document.readyState` would actually exist in these earlier browsers, but not be implemented correctly when tested (except for `readyState === 'complete'`), but this is not in the documentation.

On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) it shows that `Element.getAttribute()` is not supported fully until Chrome 29, Firefox 23 and Safari 6, which is significant as previous editions of these browsers have a combined 1.33% market share.

I know for a fact via testing in Browserstack that the `.getAttribute` method exists in Safari 4, 5.1, and Chrome 10, but it's not currently possible for me to test any earlier than that, and I don't know if these earlier browsers' implementations of `getAttribute` are buggy in ways that I haven't found out yet. For instance, `getAttribute('style')` returns an `object` in IE6.

There is also not a real workaround to these methods that I know of.

In general, I want to know if I can trust a property or method to both exist and to be implemented properly from version 1 of a browser, not version 29, especially where the DOM is concerned. Especially in Safari's case, where you would think based on MDN that version 5.1 supports practically nothing at all.

Here for instance, it says that following properties are essentially [supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=getElementById) everywhere, but I need to know if the standard implementations of these methods are also supported without errors. (Which they clearly don't really, since jQuery 1.12 exists, so I'm back to square one).

And QuirksMode's Compat Tables, which CanIUse seems to be based on, seem to have been tested on browser versions later than version 1, which is only partly helpful.

HeLp!

Comment: Why do you need to know the specifics for what are essentially dead browser versions? The way to do it is to install those versions and test, but that doesn't seem particularly useful if no one is using them anymore.

Comment: Safari 5.1 has a 1% market share, which for me is significant. Otherwise you are right, but I still want to know that after a certain point my code will stop working. There is no thin red line with regards to browser-specific implementation of a method. And the very least I need to know that `get/set/hasAttribute` will work properly everywhere.

Comment: This: _Safari 5.1 has a 1% market share_ - Perhaps the view is skewed too much toward browser installations vs buying customers. Perhaps a better metric is _what percentage of your conversions (whatever that means to you - end result benefit to your organization) comes from Safair 5.1_ - That number isn't 1%.

Comment: Sure, but if my code works incorrectly on this version because I overlooked a browser-specific error on a core DOM method, then that number will 100% be 0%. ;-)

Comment: do us a favour and stop supporting VERY old browser that makes ppl not want to update their browsers. Tell them to update and do all of us a favour

Comment: haha yes indeed...